# Regular expression that matches a pattern as well as any number of comma space separated repetitions

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, repeat, re2

What regular expression matches the below

- a pattern that's composed of two letters and numbers
- any comma-space repetitions of said pattern

Assume the below cells, their contents and the times the pattern is repeated

| Cell | Content | Repetitions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | CC148 | 0 |
| A2 | CC249, CC193 | 1 |
| A3 | CC345, CC856, CC749 | 2 |

For simplicity, I will refer to the regular expression I need as **myRegEx**

| Content | Formula | Expected Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CC148 | REGEXMATCH(A1, myRegEx) | TRUE |
| CC249, CC193 | REGEXMATCH(A2, myRegEx) | TRUE |
| CC345, CC856, CC749 | REGEXMATCH(A3, myRegEx) | TRUE |

The below expressions for each respective cell would return true, but the problem is that I'm after one expression that gets the job done, independently of the number of repetitions.

- `CC\d+`
- `CC\d+, CC\d+`
- `CC\d+, CC\d+, CC\d+`

The below expression didn't bring the desired outcome

- `(CC\d+)|.`

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: `CC\d+` returns `TRUE` for all `A1:A3`. It doesn't need to match from start to end. It will return `TRUE` as long as there's one match anywhere in the string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(" "&A1:A10&",", REPT(" CC\d+,", 
 LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A10, "[^,]", ))+1)))
```

[image]